# Javascript click event not working in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search function in which the user selects a date range, and search box if desired, and it loads the query results dynamically into an HTML div element. When the results are displayed, there is a selection box to select a field to sort by. When the user selects a field, it triggers another AJAX request which "dynamically reloads" the page into the div element again, sorting the results by the selected field. The method I am currently using works just fine under Mozilla Firefox, but does not work under Google Chrome.

Here is the JS file that handles the AJAX request:

```
/*========================================================
    sendServiceRequest.js: handles ajax request for
    dynamically loading data
*/
function sendServiceRequest(file, nvpSendData, successCallback, failCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: file,
        data: nvpSendData,
        dataType: 'html'
    }).success(function(data, status) {
        console.log(".done");
        console.log("Return AJAX status: " + status);
        //console.log("success data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        successCallback(data, status);
    }).fail(function(data, status, error) {
        console.log(".fail");
        console.log("Return AJAX status: " + status);
        //console.log("Return data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        failCallback(data, status, error);
    });
}


function sendSortServiceRequest(searchType, fromDate, toDate, searchString, column, order) {
    sendServiceRequest(
        "/search/get_content.php",
        {action:"sort", search_type:searchType, from_date:fromDate, to_date:toDate, search_str:searchString, col:column, order:order},
        function(data, status) {
            $('#results-container').html(data);
        },
        function(data, status, error) {
          console.log(".fail");
          console.log("Return AJAX status: "+status);
        }
    );
}
```

The first function, *sendServiceRequest()*, is what initially loads the search results into the div element.

And here is a fragment of the code that is dynamically loaded into a div element, the selection element that triggers an event upon clicking on an option:

```
<div class="col-sm-9" align="right">
                <label for="charge_auth_sort_select">Sort By:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
                <select class="sort_select" id="charge_auth_sort_select" style="width:100%; padding:0; margin:0;">
                <!-- selection options with datasets for identifying column and order for sorting -->
                    <option onClick="sendSortServiceRequest('charge-auth', '<?php echo $fromDate; ?>', '<?php echo $toDate; ?>', '<?php echo $searchString; ?>', 0, '<?php echo $sortArgs[0]['order']; ?>')">
                        Status
                    </option>
                    <option onClick="sendSortServiceRequest('charge-auth', '<?php echo $fromDate; ?>', '<?php echo $toDate; ?>', '<?php echo $searchString; ?>', 1, '<?php echo $sortArgs[1]['order']; ?>')">
                        Order ID
                    </option>
                    <option onClick="sendSortServiceRequest('charge-auth', '<?php echo $fromDate; ?>', '<?php echo $toDate; ?>', '<?php echo $searchString; ?>', 2, '<?php echo $sortArgs[2]['order']; ?>')">
                        User ID
                    </option>
                    <option onClick="sendSortServiceRequest('charge-auth', '<?php echo $fromDate; ?>', '<?php echo $toDate; ?>', '<?php echo $searchString; ?>', 3, '<?php echo $sortArgs[3]['order']; ?>')">
                        Order Date
                    </option
                    <option onClick="sendSortServiceRequest('charge-auth', '<?php echo $fromDate; ?>', '<?php echo $toDate; ?>', '<?php echo $searchString; ?>', 4, '<?php echo $sortArgs[4]['order']; ?>')">
                        Last Updated
                    </option>
                    <option onClick="sendSortServiceRequest('charge-auth', '<?php echo $fromDate; ?>', '<?php echo $toDate; ?>', '<?php echo $searchString; ?>', 5, '<?php echo $sortArgs[5]['order']; ?>')">
                        Insurance Type
                    </option>
                    <option onClick="sendSortServiceRequest('charge-auth', '<?php echo $fromDate; ?>', '<?php echo $toDate; ?>', '<?php echo $searchString; ?>', 6, '<?php echo $sortArgs[6]['order']; ?>')">
                        Delivery Method
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

So after the results are loaded into the div element of the 'parent' page, the user can select a field option from the selection list. When the user clicks the option, it should trigger the *sendSortServiceRequest()* function, reloading the results into the element, sorted by the selected field.

Again, this works just fine under Firefox, but does not want to work under Chrome. I've been stuck on this for quite a while now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might be easier to reduce this "bug" to hyst the front end stuff and strip out all the rest ;)

Comment: If you're using jQuery, add the tag to your question. Also, post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: for god shake use loop instead those couple of if

Comment: What does "does not want to work" mean? What actually happens in Chrome? Any errors in the console?

Comment: just use this instead hard writing those option     `<?PHP for($i=0;i<=6;i++){ ?>
         <option <?php ($col == $i) ? printf("selected") : printf(""); ?>
                onClick="sendSortServiceRequest('charge-auth', '<?php echo $fromDate; ?>', '<?php echo $toDate; ?>', '<?php echo $searchString; ?>', $i, '<?php echo $sortArgs[$i]['order']; ?>')">
             Status
         </option>
    <?php } ?>`

Comment: The console in chrome doesn't seem to show anything

Comment: It's almost as if Chrome isn't recognising the javascript event at all

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I was handling the click event, and it worked. I'm using a jquery click event in the parent page, rather than the 'onclick' method on the dynamically loaded element.

```
$('#results-container').on('change', '.fieldsort', function() {
    var opt = $('.fieldsort :selected');
    sendServiceRequest(
            '/search/get_content.php',
            {action:opt.attr('data-action'), search_type:opt.attr('data-searchtype'), from_date:opt.attr('data-fromdate'), to_date:opt.attr('data-todate'), search_str:opt.attr('data-searchstr'), col:opt.val(), order:opt.attr('data-order')},
            function (data, status) {
                $('#results-container').html(data);
            },
            function (data, status, error) {
                console.log('.fail');
                console.log('Return AJAX status: '+status);
            }
    );
});
```

Also, click events on selection options do not seem to work in google chrome. Atleast I could not get them to work at all.